# Spark partitioned data multiple files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 5 tables stored as CSV files (A.csv, B.csv, C.csv, D.csv, E.csv). Each file is partitioned by date. If I have the folder structure as:

```
A/ds=2017-07-01/A.csv
A/ds=2017-07-02/A.csv 
...
E/ds=2017-07-02/E.csv
```

Then using the below command will automatically recognize the partitions for table A in Spark 2.x

```
data_facts = spark.read\
  .option('inferSchema', 'true')\
  .option('header', 'true')\
  .csv('/FileStore/A/')
```

My question is whether I can still keep the same functionality if my folder structure was like this instead:

```
Data/ds=2017-07-01/A.csv
Data/ds=2017-07-01/B.csv 
Data/ds=2017-07-01/C.csv 
Data/ds=2017-07-01/D.csv 
Data/ds=2017-07-01/E.csv 
Data/ds=2017-07-02/A.csv
Data/ds=2017-07-02/B.csv 
Data/ds=2017-07-02/C.csv 
Data/ds=2017-07-02/D.csv 
Data/ds=2017-07-02/E.csv
```

Is there a way to read just table A across the paritions in this scenario? Or am I better off moving the data into a single folder for each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the table at the top (A, B, C, etc) then ds partition and finally the raw [same schema!] CSV files at the bottom is the right approach.

The second style you propose would require ugly hacks to make the partitions available AND to ensure the tables only having their relevant data without cross-contaminated schemas from the other tables.